# Let $x$ and $y$ be real numbers. Then $|x+y| ≤ |x|+|y|$ .

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, real-numbers

I am trying to prove the *Triangle Inequality* using both of the following Theorem.

**Theorem *5.14a***: $-|x| \le x \le |x|$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

**Theorem *5.14b*** Let $a$ be a real number such that $a \ge 0$. $|x| \le a$ if and only if  $-a \le x \le a$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

The following is my proof.

---

Let $x$ and $y$ be real numbers. Then $|x+y| ≤ |x|+|y|$ .

*Proof.* From **Theorem *5.14a***,

\begin{equation}
-|x+y| \le x+y \le |x+y|
\end{equation}

Because both $|x|$ and $|y|$ are non-negative real numbers, $|x|+|y|$ is the non-negative real number $x+y$.

It follows from **Theorem *5.14b*** that

\begin{equation}
-(x+y) \le x+y \le x+y
\end{equation}

For the inequalities $-|x+y| \le x+y \le |x+y|$ and $-(x+y) \le x+y \le x+y$ to hold true $x+y \ge 0$.

By dividing the above inequalities by $x+y$, one obtains

\begin{equation}
-1 \le 1 \le 1
\end{equation}

Thus, given that both $x$ and $y$ are real numbers $|x+y| ≤ |x|+|y|$.

---

Is the proof correct?

---

**Reference**

Daepp, U. and Gorkin, P., 2011. *Reading, Writing, and Proving*. 2nd ed. pp.55.

Comment: $\begin{equation}
-(x+y) \le x+y \le x+y
\end{equation}$ is not true. For example, if $x=y=-1$, then $-(x+y)>x+y$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ so by 5.14a, $$-|x|\leq x\leq|x|$$ and $$-|y|\leq y\leq |y|$$
Add those two together and apply Theorem 5.14b.

Answer (score 2):

$x+y$ is not necessarily non-negative, and so your proof is flawed. It is true that $|x|, |y|,$ and $|x|+|y|$ are non-negative, but this tells you nothing about what $x+y$ is.